# Linq to SQL - group by

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have three entites :

```
public class Customer 
{
   public string Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public int PhoneNumber { get; set;}
}

public class Order
{
   public string CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string OrderLineId { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public int Value { get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to do a query that would fill the model

```
public class CustomerOrder 
{
   public string CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
   public int OrderLineCount { get; set; }
   public int TotalOrderLineValue { get; set; }
}
```

So far I tried to achieve this with this linq query with group by

```
var result = from c in this.context.Customers
         join o in this.context.Order on c.Id equals o.CustomerId
         join ol in this.context.OrderLine on o.OrderLineId equals ol.Id
         group c by c.Id into cu
         select (new CustomerOrder()
         {
             CustomerId = cu.Key;
             OrderLineCount = cu.Count();
             TotalOrderLineValue = cu.Sum(x => x.Value);
         }
```

Now I have a problem with getting Name, Age and PhoneNumber from customer, they are not accessible there.

How can I solve this problem in clean and nice way?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant test this but basically you need to assign the values:

```
var result = from c in this.context.Customers
     join o in this.context.Order on c.Id equals o.CustomerId
     join ol in this.context.OrderLine on o.OrderLineId equals ol.Id
     group c by c.Id into cu
     select (new CustomerOrder()
     {
         CustomerId = cu.Key;
         OrderLineCount = cu.Count();
         TotalOrderLineValue = cu.Sum(x => x.Value);
         Name = c.Name
         Age = c.Age
         PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber
     }
```